# Google protocol buffers doesn't work with UDP?

Tags: c++, udp, protocol-buffers

I know it could be silly but my message pack defined with Google protocol buffers is not happily working with UDP while perfectly with TCP.
When I send a regular string from serialized package(in which I only have some plain fields) from client to server through UDP, every thing's fine. But when I add a repeated field, the serialized string could only be received a part of the whole. The first field will be received completely, but all the rest will be lost.
The code is written in c++, Google protocol buffers 2.3.0, Linux.
Any help is welcomed.
Thanks.

My proto file is below:

```
message Package{
    optional string virtualPath = 1;
    optional int32 num = 2;//0=insert, 1=find, 2=remove.
    optional string realFullPath = 3;
    optional bool isDir = 4;
    repeated string listItem = 5;
    optional int32 openMode = 6;
    optional int32 mode = 7;
    optional int32 Operation = 8;       
    optional int32 replicaNo =9; 
}
```

Server side:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "zht_util.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in sad; 
    int port = 50000; 
    struct sockaddr_in cad; 
    int alen; 
    int serverSocket; 
    char clientSentence[1000];
    char capitalizedSentence[1000];
    char buff[1000];
    int i, n;
    serverSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); /* CREATE SOCKET */
    if (serverSocket < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket creation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset((char *) &sad, 0, sizeof(sad)); 
    sad.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    sad.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    sad.sin_port = htons((u_short) port);

    if (bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &sad, sizeof(sad)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "bind failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1) {
        clientSentence[0] = '\0';
        alen = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
        socklen_t len = (socklen_t) alen;
        n = recvfrom(serverSocket, buff, sizeof(buff), 0,
                (struct sockaddr *) &cad, &len);
        strncat(clientSentence, buff, n);
        printf("Server received :%s \n", clientSentence);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Client side:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "zht_util.h"
int main(int argc, char    *argv[])

{ 
  struct  sockaddr_in sad; 
  int     clientSocket;     
  struct  hostent  *ptrh;  

  char    *host;           
  int     port;            

  char    Sentence[1000];
  char    modifiedSentence[1000];
  char    buff[1000];
  int     n;

  host = "localhost";
  port = 50000;

 clientSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if (clientSocket < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "socket creation failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }

   memset((char *)&sad,0,sizeof(sad)); 
  sad.sin_family = AF_INET;           
  sad.sin_port = htons((u_short)port);
  ptrh = gethostbyname(host); 
  if ( ((char *)ptrh) == NULL ) {
    fprintf(stderr,"invalid host: %s\n", host);
    exit(1);
  }
  memcpy(&sad.sin_addr, ptrh->h_addr, ptrh->h_length);


  HostEntity destination;
    destination.host = "localhost";
    destination.port = 50000;
    int current_sock = -1;

    Package package;
    package.set_virtualpath(randomString(25)); 
    package.add_listitem("item--1");
    package.add_listitem("item--2");
    package.add_listitem("item--3");
    package.add_listitem("item--4");
    package.add_listitem("item--5");
    package.set_realfullpath("Some-Real-longer-longer-and-longer-Paths");
    cout << "package size: " << package.ByteSize() << endl;
    char array[package.ByteSize()];
    package.SerializeToArray(array, package.ByteSize());
    strcpy(Sentence, array);

  n=sendto(clientSocket, Sentence, strlen(Sentence)+1,0 ,
       (struct sockaddr *) &sad, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

  printf(" Client sent %d bytes to the server\n", n);


  close(clientSocket);
  return 0;
}
```

For the problem that Jon mentioned, I tried this too, still doesn't work.

```
string Sentence = package.SerializeAsString();
n=sendto(clientSocket, Sentence.c_str(), (Sentence.size())+1,0 ,(struct sockaddr *) &sad, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
```

Comment: Why don't you use TCP? What is the reason for using UDP? (Most of the time is spent in transmission anyway, so you should use TCP).

Comment: Are you certain your messages fit entirely within 128 bytes?

Comment: There are plenty of valid reasons to use UDP; for example if you were streaming live video or audio and didn't want the transmission to stall out and retransmit useless obsolete data every time a packet gets dropped... or if you were sending multicast or broadcast data, which TCP doesn't support.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: I have a implementation with TCP, it works well, but I need the best performance that I can do, otherwise I won't have this problem.

Comment: @sarnold, that's a typo and I just changed to 1000, the problem's still there, thanks though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
strcpy(Sentence, array);
```

You're using `strcpy` - that's going to stop as soon as it hits a 0 byte, because it's treating this somewhat arbitrary binary data as a string. I suspect you should be using `memcpy` instead.

Likewise, don't use strlen later on. Avoid all functions which treat the data as text.

(In general I'd be wary of using protocol buffers with UDP unless you've got a good reason to believe each message will fit in a single packet, but that's a separate matter.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, but I don't think that's the problem, I tried the code(followed the original post), still has the same problem.

Comment: @Tony: Well, you should basically split your problem into two parts: serializing/deserializing protocol buffers, and transferring packets of data without losing anything (including the length). You should be able to reproduce the problem *either* without using sockets *or* without using Protocol Buffers. After all, the packets are just opaque bits of data - it's not like UDP understands that they're Protocol Buffer messages. (And whether or not this was the *only* problem, it was certainly *a* problem.)

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply Jon, I'm going to try now.